# create gallery page for specific post id

Tags: custom-post-types, urls, gallery

I have several custom post types similar to (place, person,etc.) refer [this](http://www.firstpost.com/topics.html)
and under each of these custom post type there are several posts inserted. (ex.http://www.firstpost.com/topic/person/amitabh-bachchan-profile-5605.html)

Each post will be having the image attachments out of which I want to create a gallery page similar to [this](http://www.firstpost.com/topic/person/amitabh-bachchan-gallery-5605-1.html).

Currently I have progressed to generate a single page for each custom post type. can anyone please advise me for the further process?

**EDIT**

You can consider the following link: www.newsmirror.agstechnologies.com/topic/place/new-delhi

see the link "View All" on the top right part of the gallery. For the time I have created a normal page and I am passing the ID of the post as the parameter to that page and using that ID I am fetching the attachment images for that post.

but that crates URL something like www.newsmirror.agstechnologies.com/gallery?id=322

but I want the link like:
www.newsmirror.agstechnologies.com/topic/place/new-delhi/gallery

can anybody help me on this?

Sorry but I cannot post the direct links so you have to copy paste the URLS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all images attached to a single post then you can use this

```
if ( $images = get_posts(array(
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_mime_type' => 'image',)))
{
foreach( $images as $image ) {
$attachmenturl=wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);
$attachmentimage=wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, full );
$imageDescription = apply_filters( 'the_description' , $image->post_content );
$imageTitle = apply_filters( 'the_title' , $image->post_title );

    if (!empty($imageDescription)) {
    echo '<a href="'.$imageDescription .'"><img src="' . $attachmentimage[0] . '" alt=""     /></a>';
    } else { echo '<img src="' . $attachmentimage[0] . '" alt="" />'; }
    }

} else {
echo "No Image";
}
```

check also this link http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-images-attached-to-posts-no-problem-but-need-to-remove-the-featured-image

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`gallery_shortcode()`](http://queryposts.com/function/gallery_shortcode/) function, that powers [native `[gallery]` shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode). It accept plenty of args and generates (semi-)usable resulting markup that can be further customized and/or styled.

Comment: can you please suggest something like creating a virtual page which wraps the gallery of images for post? and create a link through which I will be able to visit the gallery?
Preserving the URL is most important for me.

Comment: @Rohit Pande what you want to achieve there _sounds_ like rewrite endpoint (see [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](http://queryposts.com/function/add_rewrite_endpoint/)) but it's not quite my area so not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please refer to the details in question again. I have edited it and provided the exact scenario. Please see if u can help me out.